# Плавная прокрутка по секциям с изменением url

Tags: javascript, html, css

На сайте реализована плавная прокрутка по якорям, и при скроллинге страницы в верхнем меню подчеркивается активная ссылка секции. например, если мы проскроллили до секции about, в меню about подчеркивается.

Проблема в том, в url не добавляется id той секции на которой сейчас находимся. Мне нужно чтобы при скроллинге странице, в url'e добавлялся id секции на которой сейчас находимся, как только проскролили к следующей url тоже меняется.

Что мне нужно добавить в этот код, чтобы url менялся?

```
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollDistance = $(window).scrollTop() + 200;
    $('.scroll--section').each(function (i) {
      if ($(this).position().top <= scrollDistance) {
        $('.menu__link.menu--highlight').removeClass('menu--highlight');
        $('.menu__link').eq(i).addClass('menu--highlight');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Переведите на русский или вопрос закроют

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать на одностраничном html pushstate?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475099/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-html-pushstate)

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что речь о том, чтобы при скроллинге когда доходишь до очередного якоря `<a name"...">` делало активным соответствующий якорю пункт меню (видимо, верхнего) и добавляло ссылку на этот якорь в УРЛ страницы.

Ну, я представляю принцип примерно такой:

1. на onScroll контента вешается функция, которая проверяет все
   якоря `<a name"...">` и получает имя того из них, который ближе
   всего к верху скроллируемой области (или страницы вообще).
2. эта  же функция пробегается по меню, снимает со ссылок меню класс/стиль
   "активный" (если есть) и ищет там ссылку на этот якорь по атрибуту
   `href`. Найдя, проставляет ей нужный класс/стиль "активный".
3. эта же функция парсит УРЛ страницы, находит в нем часть, соответствующую имени якоря (в примере `site/#sec1?param=param1` это будет `#sec1`) и меняет ее на имя якоря из п.1. Правда, придется еще и как-то
   препятствовать скачкам страницы при изменении УРЛа, т.к. при смене
   адреса, скажем, с `site/#sec1` на `site/#sec2` страницу
   автоматически промотает до якоря `#sec2`.